# How can I allow overlapping inside card view in Kotlin multiplatform mobile

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-multiplatform

I am new to Kotlin multiplatform and trying to create list of card view with the dropdown menu the problem is I could not be able to allow overlapping like I wanted.

```
Box(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().wrapContentHeight(unbounded = true)
                .height(300.dp),
        ) {
            LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), state = listState) {
                if (notSetLabel != null) {
                    item {
                        LargeDropdownMenuItem(
                            text = notSetLabel,
                            enabled = false,
                            onClick = { },
                        )
                    }
                }
                itemsIndexed(items) { index, item ->
                    val selectedItem = index == selectedIndex
                    drawItem(
                        item,
                        selectedItem,
                        true
                    ) {
                        onItemSelected(index, item)
                        expanded = false
                    }

                    if (index < items.lastIndex) {
                        Divider(modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 16.dp))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my expanded dropdown menu implementation.

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalResourceApi::class)
@Composable
fun FavoritesCard(
    modifier: Modifier = AppStyles.Modifiers.favoritesCardModifier
        .wrapContentHeight(unbounded = true, align = Alignment.Top),
    mockFavoritesCard: MockFavorites
) {
    Card(
        modifier = modifier,
        elevation = 0.dp
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(mockFavoritesCard.imageUrl ?: ""),
                contentDescription = null,
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                modifier = AppStyles.Modifiers.favoritesItemImageModifier.weight(3f)
            )
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().weight(4f).padding(start = 10.dp),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start
            ) {
                // other contents here

                val items = mockFavoritesCard.sizes ?: emptyList()

                var selectedIndex by remember { mutableStateOf(-1) }

                LargeDropdownMenu(
                    items = items,
                    selectedIndex = selectedIndex,
                    onItemSelected = { index, item ->
                        selectedIndex = index
                    },
                    drawItem = { item, selected, enabled, onClick ->
                        LargeDropdownMenuItem(
                            text = item,
                            enabled = enabled,
                            onClick = onClick
                        )
                    }
                )
                AddToBasketButton(addToBasket = {})
            }
        }
        // other contents
}
```

My card implementation.

```
favoritesMocks.forEach {
                    FavoritesCard(mockFavoritesCard = it)
                }
```

this is how I call the my Cards.

[image]

And this is how it looks like when I click dropdown menu. I am just able to see 2 items of the dropdown menu I would like to allow overlapping and want to see all of the items.

Note: Also wanted to mention I only use shared module not able to use native android libraries.